# Call id through a Function

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to call the id from a series of Rectangles based on some input. For instance, say there is a variable named "input" that changes. I want to call the "color" field from the appropriate Rectangle based on the "input" variable (i.e. if input == 2; output == r2.color). This is what I have tried, and it doesn't work:

```
Item {
  id: main

  property var input: 2
  property var output: main["r" + input].color
  
  Rectangle {
    id: r1
    color: ""
  }
  Rectangle {
    id: r2
    color: ""
  }
  Rectangle {
    id: r3
    color: ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this valid JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare array of controls and then access them (and their properties) via index.

Probably this is your solution.

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
  id: main

  property var input: 2
  property var controls: [r1, r2, r3]
  property var output: controls[input].color

  Rectangle {
    id: r1
    color: "red"
  }
  Rectangle {
    id: r2
    color: "green"
  }
  Rectangle {
    id: r3
    color: "blue"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you may use the built-in [`children`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) property instead of `controls`.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but it's easier to lost valid indexes, when you have many controls or when you swap them. Or when there is some hierarchy of them

Comment: These seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer. It could be useful in cases, when you can't (or shouldn't) create array of controls. So, you'll never forget to add some control to array, but it will work slower, because it will iterate over all controls comparing `objectName` each time `findItemById` is called. Also you should keep in mind adding `objectName` to controls, which you are going to find.

So, you can do search by `objectName`s of items. Here is example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
  id: main

  property var input: 2
  property var output: findItemById("r" + input).color

  function findItemById(objName) {
      for(var i = 0; i < main.children.length; i++)
          if (main.children[i].objectName === objName)
              return main.children[i];
  }

  Rectangle {
    objectName: "r1"
    color: "red"
  }

  Rectangle {
    objectName: "r2"
    color: "green"
  }

  Rectangle {
    objectName: "r3"
    color: "blue"
  }
}
```